# filtered replication is not working as expected in pouchdb to couchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using filtered replication from couch and pouch db , initially i am creating a db in client side and it will replicate back to couchdb. When i add design document that document is not syncing to couchdb.

I am using pouchdb version 6.1.0

Please find the code snippet below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startbtn").click(function(){
      var dbName = 'my_database';
      var db = new PouchDB(dbName);
      var filterDoc = {
        "_id": "_design/doc_filters",
        "filters": {
            "by_type": function(doc, req) {
                 return doc._id === '_design/doc_filters' || doc.type === req.query.type;
               }.toString()
             }
    };

    db.put(filterDoc).then(function (doc) {
        startSync(db,dbName);
      }).catch(function (err) {
          startSync(db,dbName);
      });
    });

    function startSync(db,dbName){
      var opts = {
          live: false,
          filter: 'doc_filters/by_type',
          query_params: { "type": "xyz" },
          ajax: {
              timeout: 900000
          }
      };
      db.sync('http://localhost:5984/'+dbName, opts, function (e) {
              console.log(e);
          });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you checked that you have admin rights on the database? A member can not add design documents.

Comment: @lossleader as of now i dont have any authentication. so its directly accessible

Comment: This design document would already need to be on both sides for the sync to bidirectionally work as it is used as the filter. You could test if db.replicate.to() works in place of db.sync() and separate it out if so.

Comment: if you have an admin user for your instance, you need to use its credentials. Only in admin-party mode (no users configured) will you be able to write _design docs.